# Create, Sign and send ethereum Transaction

Tags: ethereum, sign

I am new in Ethereum. How can I sign an ethereum transaction. I am using `Blockcypher php-client` library. It works fine for Bitcoin. I have changed the network to `eth.main` and it works for ethereum too. But I can not sign ethereum transaction. The exception arises here in `Blockcypher/Crypto/CoinSymbolNetworkMapping.php`. [image: code snapshot] . The exception arises. I have added the blue signed lines. But I don't know what are parametes in `create` function and what value should they have. By adding blue signed code It returns following exception:
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'BlockCypher\Exception\BlockCypherSignatureException' with message '1 private keys do not correspond to any input. Please check private keys provided.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\bitcoin\api2\BlockCypher\php-client\lib\BlockCypher\Api\TXSkeleton.php on line 164`. How can I sign a transaction using Blockcypher API for my website?